# Allow application only stdin, stdout and stderr

Tags: security, stdout, stdin, stderr

Need to execute potentially dangerous binary file and want to deny access any hardware. So the process must be only allowed to have some CPU time, some RAM and work with stdin, stdout and stderr. How can I do this on Windows? On MacOS?

P.S.: preferably without any virtualization because performance is important and need to launch the process from C++ code.

Comment: PS: Please help yourself by posting this question at SuperUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it under virtual machine (VMWare, VirtualBox etc.) with no hardware enabled. Another option is to use something like Molebox which "virtualizes" an application within real system.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i need something not so heavy. I think i need to edit question and be more specific. Sorry.